# Не могу найти ошибку. Python

Tags: python, функции

Задание: Вам надо проверить, что 2 данные строки изометричны. Это значит что символ из одной строки может стать в соответствие символам из другой строки.

Один символ одной строки может соответствовать только одному символу другой строки. Два или более символа одной строки могут соответствовать одному символу другой строки, но не наоборот.

Мое решение:

```py
def isometric_strings(str1: str, str2: str) -> bool:
    val = True
    cor = {}
    a = 0
    if str1[a] not in cor:
        cor.update({str1[a]: str2[a]})
        a += 1
    elif cor[str1[a]] != str2[a]:
        val = False
    return val
```

Но `isometric_strings('foo', 'bar')` все равно возвращает  `True`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Welcome to `ruSO`, as you can understand from the postscript `ru`, here they ask questions in Russian :) Please translate your question.

Comment: пожалуйста, дайте вопросу осмысленный заголовок.

Comment: что означает "соответствовать"? Приведите пример двух изометричных строк

Comment: Да, постановка непонятна совершенно. В каком смысле "могут соответствовать", что имеется в виду?

Comment: А вот изометричны - это тоже самое, что изоморфны? А то на английском SO есть прекрасные ответы: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63427418/8324991

Comment: "Два или более символа одной строки могут соответствовать одному символу другой строки"... т.е. длина строк может быть разная?

Answer (score 1):

Я объясню, в чем проблема, но код писать не буду (неохота, кроме того, я не уверен, что тут правильный алгоритм). Проблема в том, что функция проверяет только первый символ строки str1, потому что в `str1[a]` значение `a` равно 0, а `a += 1` не имеет практической пользы, т.к. в функции нет цикла и после однократного прохода через if-elif функция успешно завершается.

Для прохода по всем символам строки используй `for s in str1` или `while a < len(str1)`. Во втором случае в ветку elif тоже нужно добавить `a += 1`.